# How to mock an exception on delegate to test a particular case on an MVC Filter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, vstest

I wrote unit tests to check for normal behavior of an `ActionFilter` I had.
Now I wish to simulate an exception on the `next()` execution so I can test a branch of the `if` statement I have. But I don't know how.

Here's my test

```
public async Task ExecuteControllerOperation_EXCEPTION_IN_OPERATION_Success()
{
    //arrange
    var actionFilter = new TransactionSupportActionFilter();
    var executionContext = CreateDefaultActionContext(new List<string>());

    //act
    Task<ActionExecutedContext> MockDelegate() => Task.FromResult( 
                new ActionExecutedContext(executionContext.ActionContext, null, null!));

    var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(
                executionContext.ActionContext,
                new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
                new Dictionary<string, object>(),
                controller: null!);

    //act
    await actionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(actionExecutingContext, MockDelegate);

    //assert
    Assert.True(executionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(HttpHeaderKey), "Missing header");
    Assert.True(executionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers[HttpHeaderKey].ToString() == Other, $"Expecting {Other} type");
}
```

I need that the MockDelegate throws some exception.

In my actionfilter I need to check on this

```
if (result.Exception == null)
{
    [SOME CODE]
}
else
{
    [SOME OTHER CODE]   //<---- i NEED the exception to go here
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `Task<ActionExecutedContext> MockDelegate() => Task.FromException<ActionExecutedContext>(new WhateverExceptionYouWant())` ? you are using `Task.FromResult` and you didn't notice that there is `Task.FromException` ?

Comment: This throws the exception here
    var result = await next(); //<--- here and not as result.Exception so it totaly breaks


                if (result.Exception == null)

Comment: but where you have `result.Exception` ?

Comment: That's not how that works. If `next()` is `async Task<TResult>` and you `await` it, you need to wrap that call in try/catch because `result` will be of type `TResult` not `Task<TResult>`.

Comment: ... or use `ContinueWith(task=> {})` and check for `task.Exception`